# Can we fetch gps location of one android device and show it in another android device?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-mapview, android-maps

Can we fetch gps location of one android device and show it in another android device? Kindly give suggestions and sample code. Need to know whether gps data can be posted from an android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its entirely possible. 
Steps:

1) Get GPS Location

2) POST to Server somewhere using JSON/XML or 2nd device if you have its IP Address

3) 2nd Device Polls Server or uses GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) to get the Location off the server

4) Display Location on 2nd device.

Comment: do u have a sample code which can help my new project

Comment: #smallTip 
use web sockets or XMPP if u don't like GCM.... this gives a real time data transfer and reduces the HTTP header overhead.

Comment: @abhilnair Google it buddy...!!